# Passing resultSet to Java method

Tags: java, generics, jdbc, orm, resultset

I try to use a resultSet and pass the values to a Java method. I get an error: INFORMATION: null

```
public static class WeatherInfo {
        private Date date;
        private int maxTemp;
        private int meanTemp;
        private int minTemp;
        private int dewPoint;
        private int d.......
```

CONSTRUCTOR:

```
public WeatherInfo(String Date2, int maxTemp1, int meanTemp1,
                int minTemp1,......)

// I convert the database Date to sql.Date so that I can use it in Java:

java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date2);

this.date = sqlDate;
this.maxTemp = maxTemp1;
this.meanTemp = meanTemp1;
.
.
.
```

SOME METHODS:

```
}

        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public int getMaxTemp() {
            return maxTemp;
        }

        public int getMeanTemp() {
            return meanTemp;
        } .....
```

GETTING DATA:

private static List weatherData;

```
Query query = new Query();
        ResultSet rs = query.loadWeather();

        try {

            while (rs.next()) {
                Date Date1 = rs.getDate(1);
                int maxTemp1 = rs.getInt(2);
                int meanTemp1 = rs.getInt(3);
                int minTemp1 = rs.getInt(4);
                int dewPoint1 = rs.getInt(5);
                int meandewPoint....

                try {

                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    // I convert the Date from the database to a String that I use in the  //Constructor.
                    String Date2 = df.format(Date1);



                    weatherData = Arrays.asList (

                            new WeatherInfo("2013-1-6", -4, -7, -9, -4, -8, -10, 100, 97, 93, 1027, 1023, 1021, 10, 9, 2, 16, 8, 29, 4, 7, 4, 74),


                            new WeatherInfo(Date2, maxTemp1, meanTemp1, minTemp1, dewPoint1, meanDewPoint1, ....)

                            );
                 } catch (ParseException pe) {
                     throw new RuntimeException("This should not happen!", pe);
                 }
             System.out.println(weatherData);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();}
        }

 public List<WeatherInfo> getWeatherData() {
        return weatherData;
    }
```

The first hardcoded weatherInfo("2013-1-6", -4, -7, -9,.....) works properly.

The second weatherInfo(Date2, maxTemp1, meanTemp1,.....) doesn't seem to work. I don't know how to pass the resultSet to weatherInfo()

**How to pass the resultSet properly as variables to weatherInfo() ?**

HINTS:

I do get values from the resultSet when I'm using

```
System.out.println(Date2); // returns 2013-01-01
```

THIS IS THE VIEW:

```
public ChartsTutorial() {

            // A layout structure used for composition

            final VerticalLayout mainLayout = new VerticalLayout();
            mainLayout.setMargin(true);

            ChartsData data = new ChartsData();

            mainLayout.addComponent(getWeatherChart(data));

            mainLayout.setSizeFull();

            setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);
        }

    private Chart getWeatherChart(ChartsData data) {
        Chart chart = new Chart();
        Configuration conf = chart.getConfiguration();
        conf.setTitle("Turku, Finland 2013");

        conf.getChart().setType(ChartType.LINE);

        BeanItemContainer<WeatherInfo> weatherContainer =
                new BeanItemContainer<WeatherInfo>(
                        WeatherInfo.class, data.getWeatherData());

        ContainerDataSeries temp = new ContainerDataSeries(weatherContainer);
        temp.setName("Temperature");
        temp.setXPropertyId("date");    // will call WeatherInfo.getDate()
        temp.setYPropertyId("maxTemp"); // will call WeatherInfo.getMaxTemp()

        conf.getxAxis().setTitle("Date");
        conf.getxAxis().setType(AxisType.DATETIME);
        conf.getyAxis().setTitle("Temperature (°C)");

        ContainerDataSeries humidity = new ContainerDataSeries(weatherContainer);
        humidity.setName("Humidity");
        humidity.setXPropertyId("date");            // will call WeatherInfo.getDate()
        humidity.setYPropertyId("meanHumidity");    // will call WeatherInfo.getMeanHumidity()
        humidity.setPlotOptions(new PlotOptionsColumn());

        weatherContainer.addContainerFilter(new Filter() {
            @Override
            public boolean passesFilter(Object o, Item item) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
                Date date = (Date)item.getItemProperty("date").getValue();
                return date.getDay() == 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean appliesToProperty(Object o) {
                return "date".equals(o);
            }
        });

        conf.addSeries(humidity);
        conf.addSeries(temp);

        YAxis humidityYAxis = new YAxis();
        humidityYAxis.setTitle("Humidity (%)");
        humidityYAxis.setMin(0);
        humidityYAxis.setMax(150);
        humidityYAxis.setOpposite(true);
        conf.addyAxis(humidityYAxis);
        humidity.setyAxis(humidityYAxis);

        return chart;
    }
```

The issue:
new WeatherInfo("2013-1-6", -4, -7, -9, .....) gets plotted correctly.
new WeatherInfo(Date2, maxTemp1, meanTemp1, minTemp1....) doesn't get plotted.

After clicking the button, the first new WeatherInfo() gets plotted, the second not. I see this in the Eclipse console:
Feb 12, 2015 5:16:08 PM com.example.project.LoginView buttonClick
INFORMATION: null

THE DATABASE TABLE:

```
-- Table: "WeatherData"

-- DROP TABLE "WeatherData";

CREATE TABLE "WeatherData"
(
  date date NOT NULL,
  "maxTemp" integer,
  "meanTemp" integer,
  "minTemp" integer,
  "dewPoint" integer,
  "meanDewPoint" integer,
  "minDewPoint" integer,
  "maxHumidity" integer,
  "meanHumidity" integer,
  "minHumidity" integer,
  "maxSeaLevelPressure" integer,
  "meanSeaLevelPressure" integer,
  "minSeaLevelPressure" integer,
  "maxVisibility" integer,
  "meanVisibility" integer,
  "minVisibility" integer,
  "maxWindSpeed" integer,
  "meanWindSpeed" integer,
  "maxGustSpeed" integer,
  precipitation integer,
  "cloudCover" integer,
  events integer,
  "windDirection" integer,
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (date)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "WeatherData"
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Maybe a ORM-mapping issue, I don't know. I am grateful for any hints or thoughts. thanks again.

UPDATE NUMBER 3:

I added more new WeatherInfo data for testing purposes. Indeed, only the first new WeatherInfo("2013-1-6", -4, ...) gets read and plotted. This is strange. So yes, the error has to do with the list probably...

```
weatherData = Arrays.asList (

                            new WeatherInfo("2013-1-6", -4, -7, -9, -4, -8, -10, 100, 97, 93, 1027, 1023, 1021, 10, 9, 2, 16, 8, 29, 4, 7, 4, 74),
                            new WeatherInfo("2013-1-7", -5, -6, -3, -4, -8, -10, 103, 91, 98, 1011, 1010, 1012, 12, 3, 5, 13, 5, 25, 6, 1, 2, 44),
                            new WeatherInfo("2013-1-8", 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 100, 98, 93, 1021, 1015, 1013, 10, 7, 1, 13, 10, 27, 3, 8, 3, 230),
                            new WeatherInfo(Date2, maxTemp1, meanTemp1, minTemp1, dewPoint1, meanDewPoint1,....) 
                            );
```

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't seem to work.`? What error (exception) are you getting and can you post the exception if it does occur?

Comment: Why are you converting a `java.sql.Date` to a `String` and then back to a `java.sql.Date`? It would be better to pass the date you got from the result set directly to your method.

Comment: The error is: INFORMATION: null, no other information unfortunately. I want to pass the resultSet to weatherInfo(). I guess it doesn't get passed properly to the weatherInfo() method.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I wanted to make sure the formatting is the same as in the newWeatherInfo("2013-1-6".....) I hacked around, so maybe this part isn't needed anymore.

Comment: Which line gives you the error, and is it one of the lines that you have shown us?

Comment: There is a problem with the List you create, but I'm not sure if  it's the only problem or what you're seeing. Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Something minimal, without the GUI, that just prints the data and still exhibits the problem? The button thing has to do with your eventListener, and that's unrelated to the code that you've shown, I believe.